# jQuery form submit and disable cookie issue

Tags: jquery, cookies, shopify

I am working on a sample system that enabled Shopify customers to add samples to their cart only once, as a cookie remembers if a sample has been added to the cart. Once an item has been selected and added the ability to add again should be disabled.

However, it seems like the whole add process is disabled. What am I doing wrong?

[Live view](https://eldecosmetics.com/collections/try)

```
$('#{{ product.handle }}').submit(function (additem) {
    $(this).find(':input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true).val('Sample Added!');
    $.cookie('sample', '{{ product.handle }}', {
        expires: 7
    });
});

if ($.cookie('sample', 'balancing-treatment-sample')) {
    $('#balancing-treatment-sample-wrap').addClass("added");
    $('#balancing-treatment-sample-buy').prop('disabled', true).val('Sample Added!');
} else {}
if ($.cookie('sample', 'cleanser-mask-sample')) {
    $('#cleanser-mask-sample-wrap').addClass("added");
    $('#cleanser-mask-sample-buy').prop('disabled', true).val('Sample Added!');
} else {}
```

Comment: why does `Moisturizer Sample` and `Cleanser & Mask Sample` already shown as added, i never added them they just show up added by default, as soon you land on the page

Comment: That's what my question is. Why are they disabled already? If i remove the if's, they show...

Comment: I suggest making your life easier and using localstorage

Comment: Can they add each sample once for a total of 3 or only 1 of 3 samples?

Comment: They can add all three types of samples, but three samples to the cart only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the library you have used is no lnger maintained now [$.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) instead

The following snippet accesses the current domain's local Storage object and adds a data item to it using `Storage.setItem()`.

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
```

The syntax for reading the localStorage item is as follows:

```
var cat = localStorage.getItem("myCat");
```

The syntax for removing the localStorage item is as follows:

```
localStorage.removeItem("myCat");
```

moreover, you need to store all added items in the cart and keep them disabled so you need a collection of an array but `localStorage` doesn't support them so you can convert them to `JSON` string with `JSON.stringify()` and then `JSON.parse()` them to reuse. Change your script to

```
$('#{{ product.handle }}').on('submit', function (additem) {
    $(this).find(':input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true).val('Sample Added!');
    let CartNotEmpty = localStorage.getItem('sample') !== null;
    let itemsCart = CartNotEmpty ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('sample')) : Array();
    itemsCart.push('#{{ product.handle }}');
    localStorage.setItem('sample', JSON.stringify(itemsCart));
});


let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('sample'));


if ($.inArray('#balancing-treatment-sample', cart) !== -1) {
    $('#balancing-treatment-sample-wrap').addClass("added");
    $('#balancing-treatment-sample-buy').prop('disabled', true).val('Sample Added!');
}
if ($.inArray('#cleanser-mask-sample', cart) !== -1) {
    $('#cleanser-mask-sample-wrap').addClass("added");
    $('#cleanser-mask-sample-buy').prop('disabled', true).val('Sample Added!');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The first part of the code works well. However, the last part makes does not enable it to add to cart. Check the live view now with the whole code you provided added.

Comment: have you added the code in a separate file this time? as i cant see the code in the view source of the page can you add those checks inside the `$(document).ready()` section and add `console.log(cart)` after adding `document.ready()` in the very first line before the if else start.

Comment: and there are several errors related to poper.js for bootstrap is missing too, try to remove those errors, see the console.

Comment: oops I have `localStorage.removeItem('sample');` statement that was for testing, just before the`if ($.inArray('balancing-treatment-sample', cart)) {` , please remove it , i will update the code @VemundEldegard

Comment: check now replace the code from above and update the live site and verify @VemundEldegard

Comment: I have updated now. Do you see the code? Still doesn't seem to work. How do I remove the saved once just to check? I dont see if else in your code? Where do I put console.log(cart)?

Comment: yeah the code is there now but the thing is i thought this code block will run for all 3 forms on the page `balancing-treatment-sample`, `cleanser-mask-sample` and `eyes-serum-sample` but it is for only the `balancing-treatment-sample' ?

Comment: @VemundEldegard I was checking wrong in the if check `$.inArray()` return `-1` if not found match instead of `false`, replace code now, and it will work correctly just make sure to call `localStorage.removeItem('sample');` inside the browser `console` before you refresh after uploading to clear previous values. I will shoot myself if it wont work now :D

Comment: Haha! Thank you so much for your help, very much appreciated. I have updated your code, and the samples can now be seen and added. However it does not hide once you add the sample to cart yet?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code where we are hiding anything neither the one provided by you or me, what is it that needs to be hidden and when ?

Comment: Ohhh! you are talking about after refreshing the page, aren't you? the items that are added are not disabled, just fixed it too, update the code again, and all will work fine @VemundEldegard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159864/discussion-between-vemund-eldegard-and-muhammad-omer-aslam).